# pandas plot with twiny top xticks anchor adjustment

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have two long xticks with twiny plot. the bottom label looks good! two issues:

1. The labels looks like has been cut out.
2. The top label far way side point to the tick, how to adjust the near side point to the tick? (use different rotation?)

---

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
df1 = pd.DataFrame()
idx = 0
for i in range(1,50):
    df1.loc[idx,'name'] = 'AAAAAAAAAA' + str(i)
    df1.loc[idx,'value'] = 40*i
    idx += 1
    
df2 = pd.DataFrame()
idx = 0
for i in range(1,50):
    df2.loc[idx,'name'] = 'BBBBBBBBBB' + str(i)
    df2.loc[idx,'value'] = i*i
    idx += 1
ax2 = ax.twiny()
df1.plot(x='name',y='value',ax=ax)
df2.plot(x='name',y='value',ax=ax2)

fig.autofmt_xdate(rotation=45)
#plt.savefig(pngname)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: @BigBen thanks, updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some tweaks to the labels' horizontal alignment, and to the `savefig` call so that the labels don't get cut off when saving. Also, ensure you remove the `fig.autofmt_xdate(rotation=45)`.

```
ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45, ha='right')
ax2.set_xticklabels(ax2.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45, ha='left')

plt.savefig(pngname, bbox_inches='tight')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Great answer, what's the reasone autofmt_xdate doesn't work?

Comment: [`autofmt_xdate`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.FigureBase.autofmt_xdate) uses right horizontal alignment - `ha='right'` - by default. Here I think you want right alignment on `ax` and left alignment on `ax2`. So you have to set each alignment separately.